# Sitecore CM instance is unhealthy in docker

Tags: lighthouse

I am using `Docker 4.6.1`. I am trying to Setup `Sitecore lighthouse` demo from **https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore.Demo.Platform** in my localy installed docker. I am getting below error on CM instance -

```
ERROR: for tenantservice  Container "7c7ac3823d48" is unhealthy.

ERROR: for init  Container "7c7ac3823d48" is unhealthy.

ERROR: for traefik  Container "7c7ac3823d48" is unhealthy.
```

When I check log files, I found the below exception-

```
ERROR Could not update device detection database

Exception: System.Net.WebException

Message: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.

Source: System

  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()

  at Sitecore.CES.Client.WebClient.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<ExecuteRequest>b__0()

  at Sitecore.CES.Client.WebClient.Execute[T](Func`1 action, String requestUri)

  at Sitecore.CES.Client.ResourceConnector`1.Request(String endpoint, Object[] parameters)
  at Sitecore.CES.Discovery.EndpointSource.GetEndpoint(String serviceName)

  at Sitecore.CES.CESManager.DownloadBinaryContent(String serviceName, String resourcePath, DownladBinaryContentParameters parameters)

  at Sitecore.CES.DeviceDetection.IO.CesDatabaseDownloader.RequestCes()

  at Sitecore.CES.DeviceDetection.IO.CesDatabaseDownloader.DoTryDownload()

  at Sitecore.CES.DeviceDetection.IO.DatabaseDownloaderBase.TryDownload()



Nested Exception



Exception: System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException

Message: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

Source: System

  at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Exception exception)
```

Has anyone tried setting up this project on docker and faced this issue in past? Please help here in fixing this issue? Thanks.

Comment: from the error it is clear that the SSL certificate isn't trusted, could you please confirm you created the certificate and used the same domain?

Comment: yes, I created the certificates.